# How can I implement DISTINCT keyword of mysql to get distinct values parallely using threads

Tags: c++, mysql, parallel-processing

I would like to create a functionality DISTINCT keyword of mysql in c++ using hashmap or unordered_map.

I have to do this in parallel e.g. initially I have input integers in an array.

Now I have to find distinct number in array (in parallel)

Comment: Will your array change once the data is loaded?

Comment: No, the array will not change, and I have to process array parallely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the original array doesn't change and assuming the available `g++` extension for `hash_map`:

```
hash_map<int, int> distinct_elems;
for (int i = 0 ; i < num_elems ; ++i)
{
    distinct_elems[i] = i;
}
```

Since the underlying data doesn't change the `distinct_elems` won't change either, hence the code:

```
hash_map<int, int>::iterator de_itr;
for( de_itr = distinct_elems.begin() ; de_itr != distinct_elems.end() ; ++de_itr)
{
    print("%d\n", de_itr->second);
}
```

or if you simply want to look up the value within the hashmap:

```
hash_map<int, int>::iterator de_itr = distinct_elems.find(value);
if(de_itr != distinct_elems.end())
{
    <do some work>
}
```

You can do this from any number of threads with no locking since data is now basically constant.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hashmap and put all the integers there from your array. But add an extra check before you add them to the map so you don't re add them if they exist. At the end, iterate over all the integers in the map and you have your unique items:

Pseudocode:

```
for (int i=0..array.length){
  if (hashmap.contains(array[i]) continue;
  hashmap.put(i,i);
}

for (iterator over map) {
  print("unique values: " + *it)
}
```

Comment: According to this code it is an iterative solution. How I can parallize this code

Comment: @bigbang give each thread a chunk of the array and share the map with all threads. However, you will need a map which allows concurrency